# Diseño de un reporte en FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

necesito una ayuda con la generación de un reporte en esta tecnología FPDF, el adelanto que hecho es https://github.com/branmeco/reporte-fpdf y debo manejarlo los datos con arreglos y recorrer el encabezado con arreglos, he intentado y esto logre https://github.com/branmeco/avance_28-03 no he podido integrarlos el objetivo al alcanzar o desarrollar es la imagen [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por favor alguien que me ayude

Atendiendo a los comentarios que me dieron, bueno esto es lo que he logrado hasta ahora [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el avance que he hecho con los array [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pido la colaboración para lograr lo de la primera imagen

Comment: Te recomiendo editar tu pregunta y añadir el código donde te quedaste, un recorrido por el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio podría ayudarte a comprender cómo funciona SO Es, y [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para (nuevamente) editar tu pregunta o de lo contrario podría ser cerrada.

Comment: El código debe ir _en la pregunta_. Lee [ask].

Comment: No vamos a correr TODO el proyecto para ver cómo está saliendo el reporte actualmente. Ten en cuenta que somos todos voluntarios que pasamos a ver a quién podemos ayudar (pero el trabajo pago siempre va primero, acá estamos mientras compilan las cosas :)  ). Revisa los comentarios que te dejaron y los enlaces. Haz un ejemplo mínimo que podamos revisar y que no dependa de que borres tu repositorio un día (para que le sirva a otros en el futuro)